# Keyboard problems, keys messed up

Tags: keyboard

Few minutes ago my keyboard messed up, when i press one key two symbols appear
for example when i press g it comes out as bg
when pressing enter it printscreens

any idea how to bring it to normal?

Comment: To be honest:  i would either unplug and replug it or simple reboot to see if the problem persists or not.

Answer (score 0):

First, go to Control Options and check out the physical keyboard type from the list: qwerty, dvorak, 102 keys, 105 keys, etc. Choose the most appropriate model.

Open an 'on-screen keyboard' app (e.g. florence) and see how your real keys are really mapped. Most probably you switched your keyboard language by mistake and ended up with some non-standard layout for another language. Switch it back to default en (or whatever you've been using before) by clicking on language icon on the taskbar.